# VB.NET - how to rectify ".DistinctBy() doesn't return a value on all code paths" warning

Tags: vb.net, ienumerable

Recently I needed way to pull distinct values from a List based upon a particular Object property (in this case, a Timestamp in `DateTime` format) so after some cursory Googling I came across a SO thread where someone provided an extension called 'DistinctBy()' which iterates through a collection and returns items with distinct property values. The code is below;

```
<Extension()> _
    Public Function DistinctBy(Of TSource, TKey)(source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), keySelector As Func(Of TSource, TKey)) As IEnumerable(Of TSource)
        Dim seenKeys As New HashSet(Of TKey)()
        For Each element As TSource In source
            If seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)) Then
                Return CType(element, Global.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TSource))
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

The code was originally in C# but I used a code converter to change it into Visual Basic. That said, I'm getting a warning in VS2013 stating that the function doesn't return a value on all codepaths. I'm aware of what the error means and how, in normal circumstances, one would go about fixing them. However, I'm not sure how to proceed considering this is a function which returns an IEnumerable object. I'm not familiar with how IEnumerable functions work and I don't even know whether the function will work at all!

Can anyone provide any clarity on this situation?

Comment: The original code contained state machines with the `yield` keyword. Meanwhile VB.NET supports it too.

Comment: Automated code converters are famously unreliable things.  What *should* the method return?  What does it *do*?  What should it return if `source` is empty or if that `If` condition is never satisfied?

Comment: Looks like the typical hack job done by a converter.  VB.NET didn't used to support iterators so they had to come up with something else.  The logic looks pretty broken, you are surely better off posting the original C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [original code](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) contained state machines with the [`yield`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) keyword. Meanwhile [VB.NET supports it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156729(v=vs.110).aspx). It's the famous deferred execution of LINQ.

```
<Extension()> _
Public Iterator Function DistinctBy(Of TSource, TKey)(source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), keySelector As Func(Of TSource, TKey)) As IEnumerable(Of TSource)
    Dim seenKeys As New HashSet(Of TKey)()
    For Each element As TSource In source
        If seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)) Then
            Yield element
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

If you had to support a .NET version that doesn't know `Yield`, you could use this approach which returns all items at once:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function DistinctBy(Of TSource, TKey)(source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), keySelector As Func(Of TSource, TKey)) As IEnumerable(Of TSource)
    Dim seenKeys As New HashSet(Of TKey)()
    Dim list = new List(Of TSource)
    For Each element As TSource In source
       If seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element))
            list.Add(element)
       End If
    Next
    return list
End Function
```

Comment: In the second case you lose the deferred execution

Comment: Sure. That's mentioned

Comment: Is there a particular library you need to add in order to use `Yield`? The only reason I ask is that it's not immediately usable for me - VS says that "Yield is not declared" yadda yadda...

Comment: What.vb.net version do you use? It was added with visual studio 2012

Comment: @Fredulom : `Yield` is a keyword supported in the newer VB versions. Use Tim's second solution instead if it isn't supported in the version you're using.

Comment: I've currently got Visual Studio 2013 - I know I've used it in the past but it doesn't want to work here for some reason.

Comment: Ahh - I hadn't added the `Iterator` modifier. Thanks all!

Comment: @Fredulom: yes, that's mandatory in VB.NET. Sorry, i've forgotten to mention it. But the compiler should have told you. I get a compiler error: "'Yield' can only be used in a method marked with the 'Iterator' modifier"

Answer (score 1):

It was (probably) an iterator method (using `yield`) in the initial C# code.
It should also be available in VB.Net for you so the correct conversion would be

```
<Extension()> _
Public Iterator Function DistinctBy(Of TSource, TKey)(source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), keySelector As Func(Of TSource, TKey)) As IEnumerable(Of TSource)
    Dim seenKeys As New HashSet(Of TKey)()
    For Each element As TSource In source
        If seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)) Then
            Yield element
        End If
    Next
End Function
```